# jq to set several explicit properties at once

Tags: json, jq

In a very simplified senes, I would like to take an existing JSON object and use `jq` to add/update two additional values to it. For example

| Start | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `{}` | `{"a": 1, "b":2}` |
| `{"a":42}` | `{"a": 1, "b":2}` |
| `{"a":"hello"}` | `{"a": 1, "b":2}` |
| `{"b":"qwerty"}` | `{"a": 1, "b":2}` |

I can set either `a` or `b` with two back to back commands like so `echo {} | jq '.a=1' | jq '.b=2'`. But I was wondering if there is a way to make only a single `jq` call to do both operations?

Comment: Pipe within jq: `… | jq '.a=1 | .b=2'`. Or add a single object to the current context: `… | jq '. + {a:1, b:2}'`

Comment: So you always return `{"a":1, "b":2}`? (Or do you want to keep other existing properties?)